Yoga Sutras - Klishta and Aklishta
Patanjali mentions the two types of vrittis in YS 1.5 and says they are klishta and akilshta and are five-fold. In YS 1.6 he lists the five-fold Vrittis.From 1.7 - 1.11 he further describes the fivefold vrittis. But he does not say which of these vrittis are klishta and which are aklishta. I have read through the Sutras, but I couldn't find any that lists the klishta vrittis.
YS 2.3 lists 5 kleshas (afflictions).
Vyasa's Bhashya links these 5 kleshas to viparyaya (unreal cognition) and so do other commentaries.
But I could not find any sutras in YS which clearly states which of the 5 vrittis are klishta and which are aklishta.
Will be grateful for enlightenment which of the five vrittis are klishta.

The vrittis are not strictly classified as kliṣṭāḥ or akliṣṭāḥ due to their overlapping manifestations in the mind. Please refer to the below translations.
Sri Patanjali's Sutra states:

वृत्तयः पञ्चतय्यः क्लिष्टा अक्लिष्टाः॥५॥
The (mental) modifications (vṛttayaḥ), which form a group of 5
(pañcatayyaḥ), may be or may not be based upon Kleśa-s --afflictions--
(kliṣṭāḥ akliṣṭāḥ)||5||

Commentary by Vyasa:

क्लेशहेतुकाः कर्माशयप्रचयक्षेत्रीभूताः क्लिष्टाः ख्यातिविषया
गुणाधिकारविरोधिन्योऽक्लिष्टाः। क्लिष्टप्रवाहपतिताप्यक्लिष्टाः
क्लिष्टच्छिद्रेष्वप्यक्लिष्टा भवन्त्यक्लिष्टच्छिद्रेषु क्लिष्टा इति।
तथाजातीयकाः संस्कारा वृत्तिभिरेव क्रियन्ते संस्कारैश्च वृत्तय इत्येवं
वृत्तिसंस्कारचक्रमनिशमावर्त्तते तदेवम्भूतं चित्तमवसिताधिकारमात्मकल्पेन
व्यवतिष्ठते प्रलयं वा गच्छतीति॥५॥

An excerpt from the above commentary is:

The Akliṣṭa(vṛtti-s) (akliṣṭāḥ) even (api) are (patitāḥ) in the stream
or flow (pravāha) of Kliṣṭa(vṛtti-s) (kliṣṭāḥ). The Akliṣṭa(vṛtti-s)
(akliṣṭāḥ) are (bhavanti) even (api) in the holes or gaps (chidreṣu)
of Kliṣṭa(vṛtti-s) (kliṣṭa) (and) Kliṣṭa(vṛtti-s) (kliṣṭāḥ iti)
(arise) in the holes or gaps (chidreṣu) of Akliṣṭa(vṛtti-s) (akliṣṭa)|

The grouping of vrittis into five is only to give a sense of the multitude of impressions arising in the mind until they've been suppressed (sarva vritti niroddhe) which leads to asamprajñātaḥ samādhiḥ as stated by Vyasa in his commentary to Sutra 1.

Sarvavṛttinirodhe tvasamprajñātaḥ samādhiḥ||1||


Thank you very much for your clarification.
The transaltion of 1.5 that has been quoted says ".................may or may not be based on Klesas...........". The Sutra does not contain this phrase. Is it implied?
The beginning of Vyasa's Bhashya commentary quoted above says "क्लेशहेतुकाः कर्माशयप्रचयक्षेत्रीभूताः क्लिष्टाः।". The transaltion that I could find for this is "The painful are those that cause the afflictions and become the field for the growth of the vehicle of actions (karmāśaya)."

Also: ख्यातिविषया गुणाधिकारविरोधिन्योऽक्लिष्टाः। The not-painful are those that have discrimination for their object and which oppose the functioning of the “qualities.”
Also, the Aklishta are between the gaps of the Klishta and the Klishta are between the gaps of the Aklishta. The commentary doen not state that they are mixed unidentifiably. They fill the gaps between each other which implies that they have their identity.
Vachaspati also states "The object is that the painful are to be restrained by the help of the not-painful".

Given the above it appears that Klishta and Aklishta are identfiable and since Vachaspati says the Aklishta should be used to restrain the Klishta, shouldn't it be known which are Klishta and Aklishta?
Not trying to argue please. Only seeking clarity.

Thanks for reading. Yes, they're identifiable through the lens of Shastra and the guidance of Sadhguru. What is good for one may noy be so for another. Ultimately, they both need to be stopped to attain the state of Yoga (Sarvavṛttinirodhe).

Thank you. After some contemplation I understood what you are saying. Each vritti can be klishta or aklishta. For example if I see something very bad happening, say a person hurt in an accident which is pramana, the vritti becomes klishta. If I go to a temple and have darshanam of the deity the vritti becomes aklishta. Thank you for the clarification. I was taught that anyone who guides one along the right path becomes one's guru. Dattatreya had 24 gurus. So my guru pranams to you.

Thanks for asking such a deep question.
